# How to replace 1$ prices with request for a quote button in Magento 2?

Tags: php, templates, magento, themes, magento2

I've almost searched everywhere in magento directories for codes related to prices, no luck !
I've also searched for it's parent div class in notepad++ "search in files" but still found nothing.
Where the heck is the codes related to prices for category products listings ?
I want to use an if else statements to show request for a quote button when the product price is 1$ . any helps ?

Answer (score 0):

You try in: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/ ? Inside has amount/default.phtml